# iOS Swift viewForHeaderInSection Not being Called

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xib

I have a UITableview  I am trying to add a `HeaderView` onto my `UITableview` .

However the viewForHeaderInSection is not being called, but I see the titleForHeaderInSection is being called or is shown. I also tried using a custom cell header for this and it also does not work.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "Groceries"

    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TransactionSpecifiedCategoriesTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TransactionSpecifiedCategoriesTableViewCell")
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TransactionSpecifiedCategoriesHeaderViewCell", bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "TransactionSpecifiedCategoriesHeaderViewCell")
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0))
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 100))

    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    return footerView

      //let header: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as UITableViewHeaderFooterView
     //var headerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 320))
    //headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    //        
    //return headerView
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 200.0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "First section header title"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `viewForHeaderInSection` method belongs to the `UITableViewDelegate` Protocol. You therefore must set the `delegate` of your table view to your view controller in order to get this callback. You probably did just set the tableview's `dataSource` as your other methods are called.

Comment: Yes. You are correct.  tableView.delegate = self works. Thank you. forgot about that .

Comment: If you uses the tableView from storyboard then you can set the delegate method from storyboard itself.

Answer (score 29):

In **swift 3**

You should call

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 44)
        let footerView = UIView(frame:rect)
        footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return footerView
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 44
    }
```

Comment: I was missing the `heightForHeaderInSection` method. If you implement only view, it won't get called. Same thing for footers.

Answer (score 8):

**in Swift 3.0**

you can also add tableView.**estimatedSectionHeaderHeight** = 40 into the **viewDidLoad** to get **viewForHeaderInSection** called

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with viewForHeaderInSection not being called in the UITableViewController, which is the delegate by default. It turned out that

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
```

was preventing viewForHeaderInSection from being called. Thus, if the delegate thing doesn't work, you may need to check that you aren't overriding one of the other section header methods.

Comment: Just for anyone trying to debug: for me it was the opposite. `viewForHeaderInSection` wasn't getting called without `heightForHeaderInSection`.